# Inconsistent Private UIPasteboard Access

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a private `UIPasteboard` with `pasteboardWithName:create:` (call it PasteBoard1) in one application (call it App1), and a second private `UIPasteboard` with `pasteboardWithName:create:` (call it PasteBoard2) in a second application (call it App2). I can access PasteBoard1 from App2 (`pasteboardWithName:PasteBoard1 create:NO` returns the correct pasteboard), but cannot access PasteBoard2 from App1 (`pasteboardWithName:PasteBoard2 create:NO` returns nil). What could be causing this inconsistent behavior? Thank you

Comment: Why not just use `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]`?

Comment: The private pasteboard is wanted for sharing potentially sensitive data between the apps, and some their interaction's logic is easiest when it can rely on the existence of this private pasteboard.

Comment: If the data is sensitive, anyone can still access the dashboard if they know it's name. You should use the iOS Keychain. Here's a good library for doing so easily: https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain

Comment: Can anyone really access it, or is just applications in the same "application group" (which I believe means applications with the same team ID, search "pasteboard" within https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/). Also, it appears that library only allows you to share strings, would it be able to handle a mutable dictionary of arrays of mutable dictionaries?

Comment: I should have emphasized the fact that using the pasteboard makes a lot of program logic very sensible, and not using the pasteboard would be a last-ditch effort.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed in the application IDs. App1 was using the Wildcard App ID while App2 was using a more specific App ID, so App2 could access the pasteboard made by App1, but not vice versa. Be careful when working with binaries built on different machines (or at least take care to know the build process for each)!